# lpSolve constraint for choices of start and length of shifts

Tags: r, constraints, linear-programming, integer-programming, lpsolve

I have a finite number of staff N, and I need to find an optimal schedule (using the least number of staff) meeting the demand

| Hour of Day | Demand |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | d0 |
| 1 | d1 |
| ... | ... |
| 23 | d23 |

where the d0, d1, ..., d23 are real numbers denoting the required amount of people on shift at that hour. Staff can only work one of a number of possible shifts with a specific start and end time given in a table. For example, it will look like this:

| Person | Shifts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0-8, 1-9, 2-10 |
| 2 | 8-16, 16-24 |
| ... | ... |
| N | 11-16, 15-20 |

So that e.g. person 1 can work from 0-8, and not work any other hour of the day, person 2 can work 8-16 and no other hour of the day, etc.

Ignoring the above constraint on the hours that each member of staff can work, the problem would reduce to:

```
min x1 + x2 + ... + x(N*24)

xi all binary variables

subject to the 24 constraints
x1 + x2 + ... + xN <= d0
x(N+1) + x(N+2) + ... + x(2*N) <= d1
... (similar constraints)
x(23*N+1) + x(23*N+2) + ... + x(24*N) <= d23
```

All of which is easy to put into lpSolve or lpSolveAPI.

I am having trouble with trying to input my constraint on the permitted shift starts/times of staff. Mathematically, for person A, this would be something like

```
xi + ... + x(i+7) = 8 where i is either 1, 2 or 3
xj = 0 for all other j <= 24
```

But I am finding this very difficult to translate into an R constraint. I have thought about using for loops but I think this is over complicating things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to re-formulate your approach.

The key decision variable here is whether person member `p` works shift `s` where the shifts appear to be particular to that person.

So you have components:

```
SETS
p ∈ People  {Bob, Tim, Cindy, ...}
s[p] ∈ Shifts, indexed by person  {1, 2, ... }
h ∈ Hours {1, ..., 24}

PARAMS
coverage[p, s[p], h] ∈ {1, 0} whether p's shift s[p] contributes to hour h
demand[h] ∈ Integers

VARS
x[p, s[p]] ∈ {1, 0} whether person p works s[p]
```

With that setup, I think the problem falls into place better.  It may be a little tricky to handle the indexed set for `s[p]` depending on the language used, but that's how I would approach this.

Comment: This cannot be solved by lpSolve then, right? Among other things, we can't get a linear objective function in x[p, s[p]] that gives us anything meaningful if we maximise/minimise in that case, e.g. I am not trying to minimise the number of shifts, but hours worked. So what is the alternative here if we can't use linear programming?

Comment: On the contrary, I think it is a great fit for an ILP.  As far as LpSolve in R as a framework, I don't know that much about that framework, but this should be doable in most expressive languages.  It certainly is in python.  As far as the objective, several are possible.  You state above minimize hours worked, which I take it would be to minimize the overage to what is prescribed in requirement.  In your post, you said minimize number of workers.  Both are possible.